# qmake template app with pre_targetdeps

Tags: qt4, makefile, qmake, distcc

I have a QT project (c++) that has a library that needs to be built before the app starts because of dependencies. My qmake file does the following:

```
TEMPLATE = MyApp
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += MyDependency
MyDependency.depends = FORCE
MyDependency.commands = make -C dependencies/MyDependency/
PRE_TARGETDEPS += MyDependency

DEPENDPATH += . \
              dependencies/MyDependency/
              dependencies/MyDependency/utilities

INCLUDEPATH += . \
               dependencies/MyDependency/
               dependencies/MyDependency/utilities

LIBS += -Ldependencies/MyDependency/dist
LIBS += -lmessageclient \
        -lmessages \
        -lssutilities \
        -lboost_serialization \
        -lcommon \
        -lmng \
        -lz \
        -lrt \
        -ldl
```

My project is very large and I am using distcc to take advantage of distributed compiling. However whenever I run make with multiple distcc nodes, my project begins compiling MyDependency in addition to my project's code that depends upon MyDependency. This causes compile errors on portions of the code that require the dependency be built beforehand.

If I run qmake and then a subsequent make with only 1 distcc node it will compile MyDependency first and then continue with compiling the rest of the project. I have also gotten this to work in other projects by using

```
CONFIG += ordered
TEMPLATE = subdirs
```

However I would prefer to keep the structure the same without having multiple subdirectories  and .pro files. Is there a way to accomplish this while still using multiple distcc nodes?